# How to re-format flextable after using delete_columns?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I am trying to generate a flextable (Rmarkdown to Word) from a table object without the extra columns that come with "as_flextable.table".  Here is what I have so far:

```
xt<- xtabs(~mpg + cyl, head(mtcars))
ft<- as_flextable(xt, include.row_percent = FALSE, include.column_percent = FALSE, include.table_percent = FALSE)
ft
```

[image]

From that I can use "delete_rows" and "delete_columns" to remove the "Total" row and column.

```
ft<- delete_rows(ft, i = 6, part = "body")
ft<- delete_columns(ft, j = 5)
```

But this messes up the formatting and I do not know how to get it back.
[image: formatting is messed up after using 'delete_columns']

How can I get back to the original formatting, where "cyl" spans the cylinder columns and there is only one 'mpg' heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result:

1. Re-Merge the header rows and columns using `merge_v` and `merge_h`
2. Re-Set the bottom border line
3. Remove the right border line
4. Finally, run `fix_border_issues`.

```r
library(flextable)

xt <- xtabs(~ mpg + cyl, head(mtcars))
ft <- as_flextable(xt,
  include.row_percent = FALSE,
  include.column_percent = FALSE,
  include.table_percent = FALSE
)

ft <- delete_rows(ft, i = 6, part = "body")
ft <- delete_columns(ft, j = 5)

ft <- flextable::merge_v(ft, j = 1, part = "header")
ft <- flextable::merge_h(ft, i = 1, part = "header")

# Add bottom border
ft <- hline_bottom(ft,
  j = seq_len(ncol_keys(ft)),
  border = officer::fp_border(
    color = "#666666",
    width = 1.5
  )
)
# Remove right border
ft <- vline_right(ft,
  i = seq_len(nrow_part(ft, "body")),
  border = officer::fp_border(width = 0),
  part = "body"
)
ft <- vline_right(ft,
  i = seq_len(nrow_part(ft, "header")),
  border = officer::fp_border(width = 0),
  part = "header"
)
# Fix border issues
ft <- flextable::fix_border_issues(ft)
ft
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is a possible approach for a custom function:

```
my_flextable <- function(xt) {
  ft <- as_flextable(xt,
    include.row_percent = FALSE,
    include.column_percent = FALSE,
    include.table_percent = FALSE
  )
  
  ft <- delete_rows(ft, i = nrow_part(ft, part = "body"), part = "body")
  ft <- delete_columns(ft, j = ncol_keys(ft))

  ft <- flextable::merge_v(ft, j = 1, part = "header")
  ft <- flextable::merge_h(ft, i = 1, part = "header")

  # Add bottom border
  ft <- hline_bottom(ft,
    j = seq_len(ncol_keys(ft)),
    border = officer::fp_border(
      color = "#666666",
      width = 1.5
    )
  )
  # Remove right border
  ft <- vline_right(ft,
    i = seq_len(nrow_part(ft, "body")),
    border = officer::fp_border(width = 0),
    part = "body"
  )
  ft <- vline_right(ft,
    i = seq_len(nrow_part(ft, "header")),
    border = officer::fp_border(width = 0),
    part = "header"
  )
  # Fix border issues
  ft <- flextable::fix_border_issues(ft)
  ft
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Stefan.  That works, but imagine writing a report with 20 or so of these kinds of tables.  It would be so much easier to just have a "include_totals = FALSE" in the as_flextable function.

Comment: (: Sure. Agree on that. Quick and easy option: Wrap all the code in a custom function. See e.g. my edit. But this depends on your use case. Option2: Make a feature request on GH.

Comment: Thank you once again!  That worked with my real dataset.  Cheers,